# How to disable menu items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I had a problem about `Menu`. I add a `MenuItem` in `asp.net`. I'm using `c#`. I want to disable Menu **Parents and Children** with user's permission.
There are 3 users which are "User","Power-User" and "BT_User". "User" have worst permission and "BT_User" have best.

How can I do that? Can anyone answer me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implemente your logic from here..

```
       if(UserType == "Power-User")
        {
        MenuItem mnuItem = Menu1.FindItem("MenuOption"); // If delete a specific item

         //to remove
         Menu1.Items.Remove(mnuItem);
         //to disable and not remove 
         mnuItem.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (UserType == "BT_User")
      { 
       Your other logic
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        if (UserType == "Power-User")
            {
                Menu1.Items.Find("MenuToDelete1", true)[0].Enabled = false;
                Menu1.Items.Find("MenuToDelete2", true)[0].Enabled = false;

                //or

                Menu1.Items.Remove(Menu1.FindItem("MenuToDelete"));
                Menu1.Items.Remove(Menu1.FindItem("MenuToDelete2"));
            }
            if (UserType == "BT_User")
            {
                Menu1.Items.Find("DeletedItem1", true)[0].Enabled = true;
                Menu1.Items.Find("DeletedItem2", true)[0].Enabled = true;

                MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem();
                item.Text = "DeletedItem1";
                MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem();
                item.Text = "DeletedItem2";

                //or
                menuStrip1.Items.Insert(index1, item1);
                menuStrip1.Items.Insert(index2, item2);
            }
```

Comment: "Menu1.Items.Find" and "Menu1.Items.Insert" doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just leverage the `Enabled` property of the `MenuItem`. There is not enough information to tell you how to build the logic around it, but when you want to *disable* one just do this:

```
menuItem.Enabled = false;
```

One thing to note here is that you wouldn't need to continue disabling any children when you disable a parent because with `Enabled` set to `false` it's not going to be allowed to fly out any children.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.aspx) for the `Enabled` property:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the MenuItem object is enabled, allowing the item to display a pop-out image and any child menu items.